# Asp.Net MVC 5 WCF validation; <required> <display>

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I have a metadata file within my WCF service that looks similar to this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports System.Globalization
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc

<MetadataType(GetType(gpsData.Metadata))>
Partial Public Class gpsData
    Friend NotInheritable Class Metadata

        <Required>
        <Display(Name:="Project Name:")>
        Public Property ProjName As String

        .
        .
        .

End Class
```

The problem is that the Required and Display tags are not being passed to the MVC application, so the validation for the fields does not work, and the names displayed are the table names assigned in the database.  For instance instead of "Project Name" being displayed, "ProjName" is displayed.

**Edit:**

Added .vbhtml file code from MVC application. I should have added this code when I first posed the question.

```
@ModelType IUD_FCL_Service.gpsData
@Code
    ViewBag.Title = "Survey Input Form"
End Code
<h2>Survey Input Form</h2>
<hr>
@Using (Html.BeginForm("SurveyForm", "GPS", FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    @Html.ValidationSummary()  @* creates a list of validation messages instead of displaying the messages next to each field *@
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    Dim fileNameData As String = "Null"

    TempData("fileNameData") = fileNameData

    @<table class = "col-lg-8">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.ProjName)
            </div>
            <div id="projectName" class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.ProjName, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(Model) model.ProjName) <---  The Html.ValidationSummary() method at the top now handles these messages.*@
            </div>
        </td>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are you sure the partial class reside in the same namespace as the target class?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, Yes

Comment: Then I have honestly no idea as to why this isn't working because this is exactly how I do it. Oh well, except for the `NotInheritable` constraint, but I cannot imagine removing it would make any difference.

Comment: Well that is worth a try.  I will try to remove the constraint and see.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work, but it was worth a shot.  There must be something else I'm missing.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, just so I understand, when you say "this is exactly how I do it", are you putting the metadata file in the service?

Comment: No, I have not tested this in a WCF service but I've done it in multiple project types. Are you *really* sure the target class reside in the same namespace *AND* assembly?

Comment: At this point I'm not sure of anything.

Comment: Haha! The reason why I ask this is because if they do *not* reside in the same namespace and assembly then the "partial" class will actually be compiled to a new "independent" class and you'll end up with two types of`gpsData`. This is a common mistake. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a little while to resolve but the problem I was having in my initial question was because I created the WCF service as a web site.

There are multiple ways to create services in VS 2013, the way I created mine was starting an instance of VS and selecting;

> **file > new > web site**, and then selecting the **WCF Service** template

Doing it this way is fine but then you can not pass the metadata created within the service.

If you created your service this way and are having problems with validation or passing your meta data, then read on.

To resolve this, **instead**, create a new project in VS;

> **New Project > Installed > Templates > Visual C# / Visual Basic**
>   (depending on what language you wish to write in) > **WCF**,  then select
>   the **WCF Service Application** template.

Transfer all of your code from the web site service to this new service and add the service reference to your application, but in addition to adding the service reference you need to add a reference to the .dll file of the service;

> In the Solution Explorer, right click **References** then select **Add
>   Reference...** then select the **Browse...**  button at the bottom of
>   the window and browse to the directory where your service is located.

For instance if your service is named TestService, then select;

> C:\...path to your service...\TestService\TestService\bin\TestService.dll

After adding the .dll you should be able to access all of your meta data within the service via function calls, and your validation should work as expected as well.